# Rename all folders in Directory to single digit or character with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I have a directory in Windows 10 where all the files have names that are too long for windows to handle.
I want to delete these files.

I have discovered that renaming the folder allows me to reduce the path name enough to delete the folder. 
For example Changing "Desktop" and it's subfolders to "1" (so the path is 1/1/1/1/file.filetype)

What I have tried is:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Filter * | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace *, '1'} -verbose
```

However this seems to throw an error on *
Is there an easy way to do this or what can I change?

Edit:

```
Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("{0}" -f $nr++)}
```

Works on one level but I am having trouble making that recursive through the child folders

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse |  %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("{0}" -f $nr++)}
```

throws this error among others:
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'designable.nib' does not exist.

Comment: Get-ChildItem will give you the files along with folders and you cannot have two files with same name.

Comment: How would I only target folders in that case?

Comment: Or Make Windows 10 Accept Long File Paths https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-fix-filename-is-too-long-issue-in-windows/

Comment: This still throws the error as it tells me the file names are too long. Which doesn't make sense as changing the path seems to fix it but here I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you will not loose anything by renaming all folders, this would help. This does not change filenames. This will recursively call the method to rename the folder until the process is able to find the next number.

**NOTE:** If you take away `-Directory`, it will update the filenames as well.

```
function RenameToLeastNumbers ($item, $number) {
  try {
    $newName = $item.Name -replace $item.Name, $number
    Rename-Item $item.FullName -NewName $newName -ErrorAction Stop
  }
  catch 
  {
    $number = $number + 1
    if ($number -gt 100) {
      return
    }
    RenameToLeastNumbers $item $number
  }
}

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path C:\Temp\Dates | % { RenameToLeastNumbers $_ 1 }
```

All the folders under Dates will be renamed starting with 1. If Dates have three folders, they will be renamed to 1, 2, 3. Same thing will happen at each of their childrens and so on.

**what folders look like**

```
dir C:\temp\Dates -Name -Recurse

1
2
3
1\1
1\1\This is a text document.txt
2\1
3\1
```

Comment: This throws the error: The script failed due to call depth overflow. It works on the first level of folders though so thank you for that.

Comment: Added a terminator in the catch to stop if after 100 files. you can change that if you want later.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this process and did not once see the error for many many directories nested in 100s of folders. (created a test folder with nothing but directories and kept copying them within each).

```
function RenameFolderAndSubFolders {
  param($item, $number)
  $subfolders = Get-ChildItem $item.FullName -Directory

  foreach ($folder in $subfolders) {
    RenameFolderAndSubFolders $folder 1
  }

  while ($true){
        try {
            Write-Output "Renaming: $($item.FullName)"
            Rename-Item $item.FullName -NewName $number -ErrorAction Stop
            return
        }
        catch {}
        $number = $number + 1
    }
}

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path C:\Temp\Dates | % { RenameFolderAndSubFolders -item $_ -number 1 }
```

Let me know how this works.